# how to find files without string having file with filenames bash

Tags: bash, file, grep

Hello I have file with filesnames, it looks like:

*names.txt*:

```
first.html
second.html
third.html
```

I need to search trough all that files and return those which does not contain a pattern. How can I do that.

Comment: don't understand you

Comment: i have file lets say, names.txt, in this file i have filenames from other directory, i need to grep through their content and find files without string pattern which is "taurus"

Comment: You need to create a [mcve]

Comment: Do you want  `grep -v`?

Comment: what is the expected behaviour if one of the files listed in names.txt does not exist or is unreadable? Should we include its name in the list of the files not containing your pattern?

Answer (score 0):

grep accepts multiple files as input, and the option you're looking for is `-L`

```
$ grep -L pattern $(cat filenames.txt)
```

Example:

```
$ cat filenames.txt
first.html
second.html
third.html

$ cat first.html

2

4
$ cat second.html
1
2
3
4
5
$ cat third.html
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
$ grep -L 2 $(cat filenames.txt)
third.html
```